# Text View not updating on button click

Tags: android, kotlin

So im creating a health app and one of the features is to get words of inspiration. So on a button click it will display a random line from an array. So on the click it does display one quote but it doesnt update to a new quote every time you click. Am i using the wrong function or is there something im missing?

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val Words : Array<String> = arrayOf("Dont give up", "Cry daily", "Just do it")
    val RandomInt = Random.nextInt(2)
    PowerTxt.text = ""
    NextWordBtn.setOnClickListener()
    {
        PowerTxt.text = ""
        PowerTxt.append(Words [RandomInt])
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw Why RandomInt is not a part of the click handker?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski if thats the issue i apologize and you're welcome to come slap me

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Okay that was the issue. Im an idiot

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `RandomInt` never changes. You only assign it once, before setting the listener.

If you want to generate random index each time you click simply do:

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val Words = arrayOf("Dont give up", "Cry daily", "Just do it")

    NextWordBtn.setOnClickListener() {
        PowerTxt.text = Words[Random.nextInt(2)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below:

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val Words : Array<String> = arrayOf("Dont give up", "Cry daily", "Just do it")

    PowerTxt.text = ""
    NextWordBtn.setOnClickListener()
    {
        val RandomInt = Random.nextInt(2)
        PowerTxt.text = ""
        PowerTxt.append(Words [RandomInt])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was an idiot and didnt put the random int inside the button click so it was being updated just with the same value

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val Words : Array<String> = arrayOf("Dont give up", "Cry daily", "Just do it")
    PowerTxt.text = ""
    NextWordBtn.setOnClickListener()
    {
        PowerTxt.text = ""
        val RandomInt = Random.nextInt(2)
        PowerTxt.append(Words [RandomInt])
    }
}
```